# error logging issue: java restful application using cxf-jaxrs with log4j2 not printing the error and exception stacktrace to file after migrating cxf

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf, log4j2

After tried to upgrade cxf & log4j2 versions in our spring java application; cxf from 2 -> 3.1 & log4j 1.x -> 2.x; the logging is broken. Rolling file appender & smtp appenders doesn't log the exceptions anymore. while running the application in maven-jetty plugin, the exception is getting printed to console. All other loggers are getting printed well but exceptions are not. couldn't figure out what is wrong.

***applicationcontext.xml***

```
<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>

<jaxrs:server id="serviceResource" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="endpoint1"/>
        <ref bean="endpoint2"/>            
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <!-- this is removed after migrating to new cxf 3 infavor of exception mappers
    <jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="cxfRestFaultInterceptor"/>
    </jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors>
    -->
    
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound"/>
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean id="businessExceptionMapper"
              class="com.commons.interceptors.BusinessExceptionMapper">
            <property name="exceptionMessageSource" ref="exceptionMessageSource"/>
            <property name="exceptionCodeSource" ref="exceptionCodeSource"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="globalExceptionMapper"
              class="com.common.interceptors.GlobalExceptionMapper">
            <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="applicationExceptionMapper"
              class="com.common.interceptors.ApplicationExceptionMapper">
            <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
        </bean>
        <ref bean='jacksonProvider'/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

***log4j2.xml***

```
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile
                name="fileout"
                fileName="../logs/web.log"
                filePattern="../logs/web.%i.log"
                ignoreExceptions="false"
                append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>[%d{DATE}] - %X{hostName} - [%-5p][%c{1},%t] - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <SMTP
                name="mail"
                from="from_email"
                to="to_email"
                subject="APIWebError"
                smtpHost="smtp_host">
            <HtmlLayout/>

        </SMTP>        
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>        
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="mail"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

**Note:** `outFaultInterceptors` was used previously but removed it and used the `exceptionmapper` in the providers section; as recommended by the org team.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved after reordering the exception mappers and logging the error explicitly with log.error. There's nothing wrong with log4j configuration.